# How to control the ios keyboard at the time of using the input tag of html

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am creating a learning Ipad app for the Japanese by using the objective-c.

The app downloads and views learning contents that has been made in HTML every time learning.

In English Learning contents of the application, There are input boxes to enter the English.

So, I want to control the ios keyboard to force the alphanumeric half size at the time of using the input box of html (or, to display the English keyboard by default),But I couldn't.

I tried using the type attribute specification of the input tag of html, but none could not be used.

I would like you to tell me if there is any good way.

Comment: I think that what you ask is not possible, only the user can change the Keyboard in iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can't force-change the keyboard on the user, Apple doesn't allow that.  If your UITextField requires a specific type of the standard keyboard, you can select that in Interface Builder or from code.  If the user has selected a custom keyboard for themselves, you can't force them to change it to the one you want.